# Adding Report Viewer Web Part to Default page programmatically

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services

I am new to Sharepoint. I need to know the best way to add a ReportViewWebPart to a page through C# code behind.

I have tried accessing the web part from WebPartCatalog. It leads me to the `NullReferenceException`.

Then I tried by creating instance for `ReportViewerWebPart` and add the properties for ReportPath, Title, etc., it leads me to `Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object` exception.

But I could add other web parts to a page as normal.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager webParts = SPContext.Current.Web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("pathToPage",System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
ReportViewerWebPart reportWP = new ReportViewerWebPart();
reportWP.Title = "Title";
reportWP.ToolBarMode = ToolBarDisplayMode.Full;
reportWP.ToolBarItemsDisplayMode = ToolBarItem.Export | ToolBarItem.Print | ToolBarItem.Zoom;
reportWP.AutoGenerateTitle = false;
reportWP.AutoGenerateDetailLink = false;
reportWP.KeepSessionAlive = false;
reportWP.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
reportWP.ReportPath = "report.rdl";
webParts.AddWebPart(reportWP, "Body", 1);
```

Comment: and some code here http://infragistics-dotnet.blogspot.ru/2010/07/adding-report-viewer-webpart.html